# Xna rotate around world axis?

Tags: c#, xna

I want to make it so that either the pitch yaw or roll rotates around the world axis and not the local axis, but I'm not sure how, I've got.

```
Vector2 mouse_change = new Vector2(mouse_previous.X - mouse_new.X, mouse_previous.Y - mouse_new.Y);
camera_angles *= Quaternion.CreateFromAxisAngle(new Vector3(0, 1, 0), mouse_change.X / 800f);
camera_angles *= Quaternion.CreateFromAxisAngle(new Vector3(1, 0, 0), mouse_change.Y / 800f);
```

Updating every frame, then I've got.

```
view_matrix = Matrix.Invert(Matrix.CreateFromQuaternion(camera_angles) * Matrix.CreateTranslation(camera_position));
projection_matrix = Matrix.CreatePerspectiveFieldOfView(MathHelper.PiOver4, device.Viewport.AspectRatio, 0.2f, 500f);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a simple answer, do to 'camera_position' the same rotation you are doing to the 'camera_angles'

```
//Add these operations
camera_position = Vector3.Transform(camera_position, Quaternion.CreateFromAxisAngle(new Vector3(0, 1, 0), mouse_change.X / 800f));

camera_position = Vector3.Transform(camera_position, Quaternion.CreateFromAxisAngle(new Vector3(1, 0, 0), mouse_change.Y / 800f));
```

Comment: If you want the camera to always be looking in the same direction as the camera rotates about the world axes, then do only the camera_position and not the angles.

Comment: That rotates around some other position, is there anyway to do it with my camera_angles quaternion?